# Qt window that stays on top of the application, but not other windows

Tags: qt, modal-dialog

I am using with a MDI workspace.
I need a non-modal window that sits above everything in the workspace (or, everything in the application), but allows interaction with the workspace.
The following achieves that effect:

```
QDialog* widget = new QDialog();
widget->setModal(false);
widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
widget->show();
```

BUT--This window also stays on top of all other application windows that are running alongside my application. (As in, if I open Chrome, my window is on top of Chrome too.)

I would like for the window to stay on top of ONLY my application.

I am using Qt 4.8, but a 5.4-compatible solution would be ideal.
I am using Windows 7 Pro SP1, but naturally a platform independent solution is ideal.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe providing your `QMainWindow` as a parent for that dialog would work

Comment: Try Qt::Tool or Qt::SubWindow flag. Maybe it will work for dialog.

Comment: @Chernobyl Thanks, but that those flags alone in this context did not work.

Comment: @Bowdzone That got me on the right track, thanks. Adding my window as a QSubWindow to my QMdiArea, along with the Qt:windowStaysOnTopHint did the trick.